# behavior of reference variable in case of arrays of inherited classes

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

Consider that I have the following given hierarchy of classes:

```
class parent{
  void parentMethod(){
    System.out.println("inside parent method");
  }
}

class child1 extends parent{
      void child1Method(){
        System.out.println("inside child method");
      }
}
class child2 extends parent{}
class grandchild1 extends child1{}
```

Now if I define an array something like this:

```
parent[] p=new child1[4];
```

and then try to initialize it this way:

```
p[0]=new child1(); // works
p[1]=new parent(); //doesn't work
p[2]=new child2(); //doesn't work 
p[3]=new grandchild1(); //works
```

This allows me to conclude that I can define the objects in the array to be only of type child1 or classes that inherit from it.

and then if I try to access the methods:

```
p[i].ParentMethod();//works
p[i].Child1Method(); //doesn't work
```

Which allows me to conclude that p[i] is a reference of type parent.
What is happening here?

By declaring

```
parent[] p=new child1[4];
```

what have I exactly declared?

I can only declare individual elements of the array to be of type child1 and its subclasses and can only access methods of class parent. What is the concept I am missing?

Comment: Why is `child1 extends parent` logically wrong? @luk2302

Comment: @luk2302 I'm pretty sure `child` in this case just means "child class", which is another name for "derived class" or "subclass"

Comment: Because if Dog extends Animal means that Dog is a Dog and and Animal. This does not apply to child parent relations. But anyway, inheritence != relations.

Comment: @luk2302: Fairly common, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

```
parent[] p = new child1[4];
```

You're **declaring** an array `p` of type `parent[]`. So, all the *compiler* knows about this array is that it's an array that can only contain instances of parent.

And you're **initializing** this variable with an array of type `child1[]`. This is allowed in Java because arrays are covariant: an array of child is an array of parent. This, however would not be allowed with generic types such as `List<Parent>` and `List<Child>`, because a `List<Child>` is not a `List<Parent>`.

So, the **concrete, runtime** type of `p` is `child1[]`. This means that, *at runtime*, the array will only allow instances of `child1` to be stored in this array. Trying to store a parent (which is allowed by the compiler since the *declared* type of `p` is `parent[]`), will result in an `ArrayStoreException`.

Again, note that this strange design doesn't exist with generic collections, which should be preferred in general.

Comment: Nice, I didnt know that (cuz I never had such usecases)

Comment: "the array will only allow instances of `child1`" it can store instances of any `child1` subclass as well

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes, and those objects are instances of child1. `grandchild instanceof child1` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
parent[] p=new child1[4];
```

You are creating an array of length 4 that can store objects of types that are compatible with `child1`, with the `new child1[4]` part. Then you are assigning that array to a variable of type `parent[]`. This is allowed at compile time in Java.

Then you are assigning a `parent` object to one of the elements in the array. The compiler thinks this is okay because it thinks `p` is an array of `parent`s. But at runtime, `p` is actually an array of `child1`s, which can't store `parent` objects. Therefore, an `ArrayStoreException` will be thrown.

Now when you try to call methods of `child1` on an element in `p`, you can't. This is because the compiler thinks that `p` is an array of `parent`s. There is no such method declared in `parent`, so the compiler complains, but in fact, `child` objects are stored in the array.